# Isuse creating Snowpipe on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, integration, pipeline, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-storage-queues

I am trying to create a SnowPipe pipeline with external stage as 'Azure Blob storage'. I am following the below link and have carried out exactly all the steps properly,but, got stuck at a point where the notification integration have to be established with Azure Blob.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Building-Snowpipe-on-Azure-Blob-Storage-Using-Azure-Portal-Web-UI-for-Snowflake-Data-Warehouse

create notification integration SNOWPIPE_DEMO_EVENT enabled = true type = queue notification_provider = azure_storage_queue azure_storage_queue_primary_uri = '<your_storage_queue_url>' azure_tenant_id = '<your_directory_id>';

I am getting this error, have tried multiple times the steps outlined in the above article but with no success.I have used correct tenant id and Azure Storage Queue url.

***SQL compilation error: invalid value [QUEUE - AZURE_STORAGE_QUEUE] for parameter 'Integration Type'***

I have selected GCP while creating a trial account in Snowflake and here in this case, I am trying to use Azure Blob Storage. I believe that Snowflake will handle this cross vendor platforms interoperability behind the hood so this should not be an issue. But, still thought of cross verifying this doubt.
I am using a Trial Version of Snowflake (Enterprise Edition). Can trail version be an issue here?
Looking for a help here.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, I am fairly sure this functionality is limited to Snowflake accounts on the Microsoft Azure cloud platform.  You can create another trial account on Azure and try these steps again.